# Cómo filtrar las filas de un marco de datos si los valores de una columna están presentes en la columna de otro marco de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos dataframe y me gustaria obtener solo los rows por los cuales el nombre no esta en la otra:

`df_sota` es el dataframe de los articulos que he leido ahora mismo:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Nom Nom 1er auteur  lien    année   Description Post-Hoc/Self-Exp & Local/Global    Technique d'explicabilité   Git/Code    OK/KO   Equipe
0   1   A Survey of the State of Explainable AI for Na...   Danilevsky  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.00711.pdf    2020    Etat de l'art des méthodologies d'explicabilit...   NaN NaN NaN OK  Caroline
1   2   QUINT: Interpretable Question Answering over K...   Abdalghani Abujabal https://aclanthology.org/D17-2011/  2017    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Caroline
2   3   EXBERT: A Visual Analysis Tool to Explore\nLea...   Ben Hoover  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Caroline
```

Y me gustaria anadir los articulos de Google Scholar que no he leido, entonces por lo cual los `Nom` o `Lien` sean differentes:

`df_google`:

```
    Nom                                                 Nom 1er auteur  lien    année
1   Teach me to explain: A review of datasets for ...   S Wiegreffe  https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.12060   2102.0
2   A Survey of the State of Explainable AI for Na...   Danilevsky  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.00711.pdf    2020.0
3   Explainable artificial intelligence applicatio...   SM Mathews  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-...   2019.0
4   Explainaboard: An explainable leaderboard for nlp   P Liu   https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.06387    2021.0
```

Por ejemplo me gustaria que no tenga en cuenta *A Survey of the State of Explainable AI for ...*. Entonces intenté obtener los nombres en df_google que no estan en df_sota con:

```
new_papers = list(set([x for x in final.Nom.values for y in df_sota.Nom.values if x.lower() != y.lower()]))
new_papers
```

Pero me devuelve el mismo codigo:

```
['Helping results assessment by adding explainable elements to the deep relevance matching model',
 ...
 'A survey of the state of explainable AI for natural language processing',
```

Así que el papel sigue ahí y es molesto. No puedo hacer `df_google.loc[df_google['Nom'].isin(new_papers)]` hasta que no

Aqui esta el [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VKy6y0XKMA2qljzbxUekMeGlpRqJfI5s?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poder filtrar directamente con una máscara:

- En `df_sota.Nom` tienes los papers que ya has leído.
- Con `df_google.Nom.isin(df_sota.Nom)` creas una serie True/False con los papers que existen en ambos dataframes
- Utilizas esa serie como máscara de selección en el dataframe df_google negándola con `~`

```
df_google[~df_google.Nom.isin(df_sota.Nom)]
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo utilizando las URLs de Lien:

```
df_google[~df_google.Lien.isin(df_sota.Lien)]
```

---

No he podido validarlo en el collab porque el dataframe de los papers leídos lo estás construyendo desde un xlsx externo